# Getting youtube videos in high quality

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api

I am streaming videos from youtube using mediaelement player. However the quality of the videos I am getting is poor. I tried to force the highest quality playback using:

```
  <source type="video/youtube" src='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WA4iX5D9Z64&hd=1'></source>
```

However, that doesn't work. How can I get back videos in there highest quality possible or specify what quality I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the Youtube API will respect the hd parameter only if the video window is large enough to handle the higher definitions ... so if your iFrame ends up only being 640x360, you will get a 360p video even with the hd=1 added. This can be changed by either increasing the size of the iFrame (or the height/width parameters passed to the API), or by utilizing the vq parameter to specify which quality you want (i.e. vq=720p or something like that).

However, your situation is complicated by the fact that you aren't interacting with the API yourself or using a simple iFrame embed, but are instead wrapping it with the mediaelement player. In looking through the source code, it appears that when mediaelement interacts with the Youtube API, it isn't passing along any parameters (in the 'playerVars' array) other than the Youtube ID itself, so neither hd or vq would have any effect. Changing the size of the player will still work; for example,

```
<video width="1280" height="720" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI"/>
</video>
```

Will give you a higher quality video than:

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI"/>
</video>
```

when you execute the mediaelement callback.

If you'd rather not increase the size of the player but still have a higher quality video, you could patch the mediaelement-and-player.js file to make sure it sends the vq parameter along to the API, and then use it in the src attribute.